# Subquery returning null from count. (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, subquery, plpgsql

PostgreSQL 11.1

*ERROR:  null value in column "chart_number" violates not-null constraint*

O.K., I'm clearly doing something wrong here, but I don't see it.

Table patients has

```
COLUMN chart_number integer NOT NULL;
```

The Error is coming from the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION phoenix.next_chart()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.chart_number is null or NEW.chart_number = 0 THEN
        LOOP
            EXIT WHEN 0 = (select count(*) from patients where chart_number = NEW.chart_number);

            SELECT nextval('chartsequence') INTO NEW.chart_number;
        END LOOP;       
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

The sequence "chartsequence" is defined in the usual way:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE chartsequence START 1;
```

What I am trying to do is have the loop exit when the sequence value does NOT exist in table patients.

Any help is most appreciated.  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `new.chart_number` is `NULL` then

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM patients p
       WHERE p.chart_number = new.chart_number
```

always returns `0` because there cannot be any row in `patients` with a `chart_number` of `NULL` since the column is defined `NOT NULL`, let alone that `=` won't work on `NULL` but needs a `IS NULL` operation.

That means that the condition

```
0 = (SELECT count(*)
            FROM patients p
            WHERE p.chart_number = new.chart_number)
```

is always `true` in such cases, which in turn means that you immediately exit the loop at the beginning of its first iteration, yet before `new.chart_number` is even changed once. It stays `NULL`. And since it's constrained not to be `NULL` the error gets thrown.

I think you just need to change the order of the statements in the loop's body. First set `new.chart_number` according to the sequence, then check if it doesn't exist. Speaking of exists, you could also use `EXISTS` here and just the assignment operator rather than `SELECT ... INTO`.

```
...
IF new.chart_number IS NULL
    OR new.chart_number = 0 THEN
  LOOP
    new.chart_number := nextval('chartsequence');
    EXIT WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM patients p
                                 WHERE p.chart_number = new.chart_number);
  END LOOP;       
END IF;
...
```

Comment: Entirely correct. Thanks. In particular, thank you for clarifying when the statement following "EXIT" is run. My (wrong) thinking was that it was always executed following the block of statements within the loop. Apparently, it is executed immediately where it is encountered. Thanks.